# uninitialized constant YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, rubygems

I'm trying to use youtube_it gem with oauth2.

in my gemfile

```
gem 'youtube_it'
```

in my application_controller

```
require 'youtube_it'
```

the problem is when I call

```
client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(client_access_token: Gg["access_token"], client_refresh_token: Gg["refresh_token"], client_id: Gg["client_id"], client_secret: Gg["client_secret"], dev_key: Gg["dev_key"])
```

the console say

```
uninitialized constant YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client
```

if i use:

```
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new
```

it's work perfect, the problem is when i try use oauth2

any idea?

Comment: you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, i force last gem version and work fine gem 'youtube_it', :git => 'https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it.git'